late 90's-2000 Fantasy film with dungeon a fairy and a witch
It must have been around 2002 ish. I recall being at a summer program away from home, and a group of college aged kids were watching tv. There was a movie on that was some flavor of fantasy. It might possibly have been a made for TV movie. I remember 2 scenes pretty distinctly.
A young man (the hero?) is trapped in a cage/dungeon, and a fairy tries to keep him there by taking the appearance of a girl he loves. He says something like "It is but fairy glamour." And refuses.
I think closer to the end of the film, an evil witch (the villain?) is punished for her deeds by being strapped to a chair and surrounded by mirrors, screaming at her own ugliness. The guy says something like "you will spend the rest of eternity looking at the ugliest sight imaginable!"
I find myself curious about this film. I think it was made around the beginning of the 2000's, but could have been as early as the nineties.

This sounds like Legend (1985) starring Tom Cruise, Mia Sara and Tim Curry. Some more here.
Oona is the fairy who takes on the look of Lili in a clip  of this exchange...

Oona: "Call that a kiss? Am I not sweet?"
Jack: "Sweeter than bee pollen on a summer wind."
Oona (takes Lili's appearance):  "Sweet is the wind that blows me to you."
Jack: "Lili?"
Oona: "Yes, Jack"
Jack: "This isn't real."
Oona: "Oh it is. I'm warm and alive. I want to be in your arms." 
Jack: "No, I can't! No, this is just more fairy glamour! Human hearts
  don't work that way."

The evil witch is Meg Mucklebones, who is the secondary villain to the Lord of Darkness.
